# 13-07-2018 00:00 Date Format in store procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle

**13-07-2018 00:00** Date Format in store procedure in Oracle.

Query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Y.YARD_NAME from MST_ACTUAL_CONSUMPTION A INNER JOIN MST_VP_YARD Y ON Y.YARD_NAME=A.YARD_NO where (TO_DATE(A.TO_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI') BETWEEN TO_DATE( '03-07-2018 00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI')  AND TO_DATE('13-07-2018 00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI')) AND  Y.IS_DELETE=0 GROUP BY Y.YARD_NAME;
```

Error : hour must be between 1 and 12"

Note: Date input like **03-07-2018 00:00**

Comment: What is the datatype of the `A.TO_DATE` column? If it's DATE, you don't need to do the `to_date()` on it (if you're wanting to ignore the time part, you should use `trunc()` instead). If it's VARCHAR2 (ugh, why? Consider using the correct datatype on it), then carry on as you are *{:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format string needs to use 24-hour to be able to parse 00:00

```
'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 24 hour times (which you are with "00:00") you need to use `HH24` not `HH` in your `to_date()` format mask,

e.g.: `TO_DATE( '03-07-2018 00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')`

If you stick with 12 hour times, you need to add `AM` (or `PM`; either works) to the format mask, and use the correct time,

e.g.: `TO_DATE( '03-07-2018 12:00 AM','DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI AM')`

Comment: I got my Solution. Thnak you @Boneist

Answer (score 0):

Date can't parse 00:00. it should 12:00. If can pass the input like 12:00 then pass that value. otherwise try below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT Y.YARD_NAME 
from MST_ACTUAL_CONSUMPTION A 
        INNER JOIN MST_VP_YARD Y ON Y.YARD_NAME=A.YARD_NO 
where (TO_DATE(A.TO_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI') BETWEEN TO_DATE( substr('03-07-2018 00:00', 1, 10),'DD-MM-YYYY')  AND TO_DATE(substr('13-07-2018 00:00', 1, 10),'DD-MM-YYYY')) 
AND  Y.IS_DELETE=0 
GROUP BY Y.YARD_NAME;
```

Comment: If you pass in 12 and use HH without an AM/PM indicator then it's treated as midday, not midnight; the 00 suggests midnight was intended. Your query is still using HH, which is a bit confusing. And using `substr` like that would only work if the time part was *always* 00:00 - which may be the case. Still seems like a bit of a hack anyway.